# Table attribute in Class tag of file.hb.xml

Tags: hibernate, jboss

error showing on deploying the project. The error is of BadSQL grammer
using Jboss and EAP Server

does usin table=nm..sd causing the error

Comment: We need details to help you... start with copy-n-paste of the error message

Comment: It seems it's not a Jboss issue per se, but rather a DB configuration.